# Как убрать полосы/неровности в изображении svg с градиентом - CSS3

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

подскажите как убрать эти разрывы в градиенте, если я вставляю картинку svg, как background в div:

```
<div style="background: url('assets/settings-lights.svg') center/cover"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал оверлей с наложением `blur` и проблема решилась:

```
<div style="background: url('assets/settings-lights.svg') center/cover">
    <div style="backdrop-filter: blur(15px)">Your content here</div>
</div>
```